# How to display Bullet In android webview

Tags: java, android

String S = "  &#8226; The provisions of section 40(a)(ia) of the Income Tax Act, 1961, are applicable not only to the amount which is shown as payable on the date  of balance-sheet, but it is applicable to such expenditure, which become payable at any time during the relevant previous year and was actually paid within the previous year";

Here  &#8226; is for Bullet But I am Unable to display Bullet In android web view Belo is my code I have tired to decode this But i m Unable to display Please tell how i will Fix it where am doing Mistake

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView web1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String S = "  &amp;#8226; The provisions of section 40(a)(ia) of the Income Tax Act, 1961, are applicable not only to the amount which is shown as payable on the date  of balance-sheet, but it is applicable to such expenditure, which become payable at any time during the relevant previous year and was actually paid within the previous year";
        web1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        web1.loadData(S, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }
}
```

Comment: I have Fixed my issue Using String re = "(?:&amp;#(\\d+);)"; This Pattern

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing

```
String S = "  &amp;#8226; The provisions of section...."
```

to

```
String S = "  &#8226; The provisions of section...."
```

as the version you're using certainly won't work.

Failing that, you could use an html unordered list by using `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.:

```
String S = "<ul><li> The provisions of section....</li></ul>"
```